# Why percentage calculation in excel gives me incorrect numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below numbers

Potiential Customers = 2791 and enrolled customers are 45

In excel I calculated the percentage as 45/2791 gives me 16.12 but in calculator it gives me 0.0161,..

I dont understand what. I also checked the "set Percision as displayed", still gives me the incorrect percentages. Any idea why?

When I calculated as 45/2791 multiplied by 100 it doesn't give the correct results and when I did 45/2791 multiplied by 0.10 it gives me the correct numbers same as calculator.

Any settings I have to change? Please let me know.

when multiplied by 0.10
[image]

When multiplies by 100
[image]

Comment: Excel returns the same as the calculator. (don't set precision as displayed) I suggest you double-check what you actually calculated.

Comment: Sounds like a mix up of thousands separator and decimal separator

Comment: Hi Rory, I double checked also removed set percision as well. I get the same results. I also attached the screenshots.

Comment: What are your **Windows Regional Settings** for the thousands separator and the decimal point?

Comment: Your screenshot shows a result of `0.75` for the presumed equation of `C3/B3*0.1`. In order to get that result, it must be that in your system, the `dot` is the **decimal separator**.

Comment: Hi Ron, Yes you are right. In my system the dot is the decimal separator. I changed it to comma and it gives me expected results using C3/B3*100. I didn't know about this settings. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please be clear about your question. Do you want to calculate Percentage or simple division?. Percentage is always `calculated/total * 100`.

1. You are getting 0.0161.. because you have not multiplied by 100.
2. After multiplying by 100, Percentage = ( 45/2791 ) * 100 = 1.61% i.e Correct
3. Why result = 16.12.. because ( 45/2791 ) * 1000 = 16.12% i.e Wrong

Hope it has cleared your doubts.

Comment: Hi Jay, This is the exact result I see when I use calculator. But my excel gives me 1.61% when I do (45/2791)* 0.10 and  (45/2791)* 100 gives me 1612.33 as you can see in the screenshots. I didn't use 1000 to multiply.

Comment: No of Potential Customers = 2791 as mentioned by you in text. But in your sheet image, Have you entered wrong number i.e 2.791 (Decimal Value ) instead of 2791.